# log4j2 in spring boot only printing org.hibernate logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to configure log4j2 in my spring boot project. I have added the below dependency along with others:

```xml
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Here is the log4j2.xml configuration I have added:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            </Console>

            <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                fileName="./logs/spring-boot-logger-log4j2.log"
                filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/spring-boot-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <!-- rollover on startup, daily and when the file reaches 
                        10 MegaBytes -->
                    <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                        size="10 MB" />
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>

        <Loggers>
            <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
            <Root level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            </Root>

            <!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
            <Logger name="com.xxx.xxx" level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            </Logger>
        </Loggers>

    </Configuration>
```

All looks good but only the following logs I am able to see in console as well as in log files:

```
      2019-11-28 16:26:34,681 INFO o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper [restartedMain] HHH000204: Processing 
      PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: AppConfig
        ...]
       2019-11-28 16:26:34,879 INFO o.h.d.Dialect [restartedMain] HHH000400: Using dialect: 
        org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
        2019-11-28 16:26:37,811 INFO o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator [restartedMain] HHH000397: 
       Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
        2019-11-28 16:26:38,381 INFO o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper [restartedMain] HHH000204: Processing 
       PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: DWDBConfig
        ...]
       2019-11-28 16:27:05,182 INFO o.h.d.Dialect [restartedMain] HHH000400: Using dialect: 
       org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
       2019-11-28 16:27:07,341 INFO o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator [restartedMain] HHH000397: 
        Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: Make your question understandable.

Comment: As mentioned, the dependencies and the xml configuration is as shown. Still I am not getting any logs like Spring boot start-up logs, Application logs etc.